# Launch Android Intent from Libgdx render method

Tags: java, android, android-intent, libgdx

I'm trying to launch an Intent from the render method in libgdx but I am getting a  "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()" error.

I have implemented the Interface from here  http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/IntegratingAndroidNativeUiElements3TierProjectSetup

I have used the Toast implementaion and that works okay.

This is my Android implementation

```
 @Override
public void launchPlayerRoom() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(appContext, RoomViewActivity.class);
    intent.putExtras(selectPlayerRoom());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

and calling from Libgdx render

```
if (health_amount <= 0){
            actionResolver.launchPlayerRoom();
        }
```

The Intent needs to be called from render as it depends on a value that is decremented in render.
I understand that the problem is calling a UI thread from a render thread(I think!) but I don't know how to solve it.
I have tried from this post [Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213538/cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare)

```
 @Override
public void launchPlayerRoom() {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(appContext, RoomViewActivity.class);
    intent.putExtras(selectPlayerRoom());
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

But this makes no difference.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Libgdx "render" thread is not the Android "UI" thread, so when you invoke code in the Android back-end that requires the Android UI thread context you have to jump through some hoops.

In general, the solution is to create a `Handler` in the context of the UI thread and then post Runnables to that object.  This is what the wiki page on integrating android UI elements is doing.

If you have the `Toast` implementation working correctly, then the `Intent` code should also work (both have the same requirement to be run on the Android UI thread context).

Perhaps there is some other problem with the `Handler` you're creating (is it not being created during the Libgdx `create` callback?  (Its implicitly associated with the thread that created it.)  Or are you invoking this code too early in your setup?  A full backtrace might provide more details.

Comment: Thanks,Tried '@Override
    public void launchPlayerRoom() {
        final Bundle extras = selectPlayerRoom();
        uiThread.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(appContext, RoomViewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtras(extras);
                appContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }' but still no joy. Tried to launch actionResolver.launchPlayerRoom() from create, that also crashed with same error.The Toast works from render method, so I think the interface is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I have now got it sorted. It turned out I needed to interrupt the render thread then I could launch the intent. I changed implementaion slightly as  I call an AlertDialog and launch the intent from there.
I have accepted the answer as it got me thinking along the right lines.

Comment: Hey Hi @jonnypotwash, How you are displaying dialog inside Render method and how you r starting activity, Can you please share your code here, as I have the same requirement to start activity from Render method.