# correct design in android multi-threading

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I wrote an app on android in which a thread is created through the main activity(UI thread), the new thread saves the activity instance and then calls a method in it while running.

I got an error "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()" and found out in this post:
[Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213538/cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare/6213637#6213637)

and in many more questions that i can't call a method of another thread directly, i should use runOnUIThread or doInBackGround and so on...

my question is WHY? 
what's wrong with that design?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Many of the Android framework's classes (especially those in the UI toolkit) aren't thread safe, so accessing them on non-UI threads can lead to unpredictable code behavior. My guess is that you're calling a method on your activity that is eventually (perhaps through its own subsequent calls) touching a UI element or trying to create a `Handler`. Can you explain in more detail what you're trying to do? Maybe post some code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem a bit confused - the question does not make much sense, so it's quite hard to answer.

Bits and pieces:

1. creating a thread in UI thread that "saves the activity instance" is wrong in itself: lifecycle of activity is complicated and you should not refer to it by instance.
2. you cannot "call a method of another thread" (unless you mean the java.lang.Thread object itself, and from the context it seems that you don't), because objects do not belong to any thread. All objects in Java live on heap and can be accessed by any thread.
3. BUT since each thread is an object, you can have a Map that holds objects indexed by thread instances. This is basically what ThreadLocal is.
4. Android introduces concept of "Loopers" - you can build one in any thread and call it; if you do, you can say that the thread *"has a looper"*. A thread that *has a looper* is stuck in a loop, doing any work that handlers pass to it, and - after finishing each task - waiting for another to come by. This is what the main thread does all the time. If you build a handler instance, the handler can be called from any thread, but is connected to the looper of the thread that called the constructor.
5. Since handlers work by passing work to loopers, they can only be built in threads that have loopers.

I am not sure what you want to achieve, but the bottom line is:

- your idea of holding a reference to Activity is wrong - just let it go (and use Loader API or a Service)
- you try to build a Handler instance on some custom thread that has no Lopper (probably adding the looper is NOT what you want, instead you want to build the Handler in your main thread)
- you imagine objects as being owned by threads - try to get rid of this idea, it skews your way of thinking.